# Substract minimum value of row from each element of row in dataframe,

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
   A  B  C  D
r1 10  7 19 11
r2  5  5  7  8
r3 12  9 13 11
r4  8 10 11  9
```

I want to create 2 data frames whose values are:

1. Subtracting `min` value in row from each element of that row,
2. Subtracting `min` value in column  from each element of that column.

I got function for column

```
d1=transform(d,A=A-(min(A)),B=B-(min(B)),C=C-(min(C)),D=D-(min(D)))
```

Result I get is is as below,

```
> d1
  A B  C D

r1 5 2 12 3

r2 0 0  0 0

r3 7 4  6 3

r4 3 5  4 1
```

what function I should use to get result for rows, which I want is

```
> d2
  A B  C D

r1 0 2  9 1

r2 0 5  2 3

r3 1 3  2 0

r4 0 7  3 1
```

(`min` value of row is subtracted from each item of the row)

Comment: Can you explain your second requirement bit more? How are you getting the second dataframe d2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the `apply` fonction with :

```r
# 1 for the rows
apply(d, 1, function(x){x-min(x)}
# 2 for the columns 
apply(d, 2, function(x){x-min(x)}
```

Comment: next step --Find Row & Column penalties by taking difference between smallest & next smallest value in row & column. for evry row and column.

Comment: Can you tell us more in another question with code and example of what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I have posted a question to you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64392514/r-programme-for-solving-tp-with-my-method @cbo

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question, you could just run your 'function for columns' on the *transpose* of your data frame. Transposed data frames turn into matrices, so you'll need to turn it back into a data frame:

```r
transpose <- as.data.frame(
  t(yourDataFrame)
)

d2 <- transform(transpose ,A=A-(min(A)),B=B-(min(B)),C=C-(min(C)),D=D-(min(D)))
```

By the way this question could be clearer. I recommend you read **How to create a minimal, reproducible Example**: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pmin`

```
d - do.call(pmin, d)
```

Or by columns

```
library(matrixStats)
d - colMins(as.matrix(d))[col(d)]
```