# R programme for solving TP with my method

Tags: r

I have developed new method to solve TP, but I am very slow with programming,
Can you help to write programe for the method???

**III. ALGOTITHM OF AOCM
STEP 1. Subtract smallest cost from every element of every row of transportation table and put it on right top of that element.

STEP 2. Subtract the smallest cost from every element of every column of transportation table and put it on right bottom of that element.

STEP 3. Create a new matrix whose elements are average value of right top and right bottom of elements of step 1 and step 2.

STEP 4. Find Row & Column penalties by taking difference between smallest & next smallest value in row & column.

STEP 5. Identify the largest penalty and allocate the maximum possible quantity to that cell having minimum value of element in corresponding row or column.
If there is a tie between largest penalties, then tie can be broken by taking difference between smallest and next to smallest element, if tie still not broken then repeat the procedure with next to next smallest and so on, if tie still not broken then select arbitrarily.

STEP 6. Repeat step 5 to step 6 until the rim requirement is satisfied.

STEP 7. Put these allocated values in original TT in corresponding cell.

STEP 8. Calculate the transportation cost of TT. This calculation is the sum of product of unit transportation cost and allocated quantity.**

[image: Problem]

Comment: @cbo please take a look here

Comment: ok, there is quite a lot ! :)

Comment: yeah. I am very slow with the programing, can you suggest me a good book to learn 'R'

Comment: Freely online you can have a look at [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/), they are more references [here](https://www.linuxlinks.com/excellent-free-books-learn-r/).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully understood your assignements after the 4th point but this should get you started (using the data provided on your 1st question) :

```r
dfr <- read.table(text = "10  7 19 11
        5  5  7  8
        12  9 13 11
        8 10 11  9")

# step 1 to 2
drow <- apply(dfr, 1, function(x){x-min(x)})
dcol <- apply(dfr, 2, function(x){x-min(x)})

# 3
dmean <- (drow + dcol)/2
dmean
#>    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> V1  4.0    1  7.5  1.5
#> V2  0.0    0  0.0  1.0
#> V3  9.5    3  5.0  3.0
#> V4  3.5    4  3.0  1.0

# 4 row & col penalties
drow_min <- apply(dmean, 1, function(x){
    xord <- x[order(x)] ;
    xord[2] - xord[1]})
drow_min
#>  V1  V2  V3  V4 
#> 0.5 0.0 0.0 2.0

dcol_min <- apply(dmean, 2, function(x){
    xord <- x[order(x)] ;
    xord[2] - xord[1]})
dcol_min
#> [1] 3.5 1.0 3.0 0.0
```

Then you could either use `if` and `else`structure in 5 ; `while` for the 6 and export your data back to excel with `readr::write_excel_csv()`.

Good luck !

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, I am unable to provide you info you needed.
here it is

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mnz7ST1VFJ3Ptim-KvxGo_kv-5y9EKie/view?usp=sharing]

This is my paper.
I hope now you can understand what I exactly want.